# Is there any limit for the size of dataframe in dataframe.corr correlation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to calculate spearman correlation of a dataframe, my dataframe size is 759 rows x 52 columns, however it seems that "dataframe.corr" just gets the first 10 columns.

here is my code:

corr_matrix = df.corr(method='spearman').abs()

upper = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))

to_drop = [column for column in upper.columns if any(upper[column] > 0.7)]

Comment: In general, there is no size limit unless you can't fit all your data into system memory. You should check `corr_matrix.shape` to see the size of the matrix.

Comment: Yes, I checked the size
Altough my original dataframe is 759*52 but corr_matrix is 10*10 !
isn't there any defaults values that I should change?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `df.corr()` only works on integer or float columns. Can you check the `dtype` of your dataframe by running `df.info()`?

Comment: Thanks
This was my issue!
the rest of the columns were of object type!